# How can I translate this? すべてかけて抱きしめてみせるよ

Tags: translation, song-lyrics

> いつでも捜しているよ　どっかに君の姿を 
> 向かいのホーム　路地裏の窓 
> こんなとこにいるはずもないのに 
> 願いはもしも叶うなら　今すぐ君のもとへ 
> できないことは　もう何もない 
> すべてかけて抱きしめてみせるよ

This paragraph of "One More Time, One More Chance" by Yamazaki Masayoshi, I'm translating to:

> I'm always looking for you everywhere I go
> On the opposite platform, through the alleys
> Even though you will not be there.
> If my wish can come true, I will be with you right now
> **The impossible would no longer be anything.**
> **I'll show that i'll hug you tight again.**

But the marked, I definitely think it's pretty wrong. But I can not think of a better way, no matter how hard I try.

Comment: The line before last is "There will be nothing I could not do." and it is only speculation but かける (last line) could in fact be 賭ける.

Comment: 路地裏の窓 through the alleys >> Are you not missing 窓?

Comment: Really miss the 窓 e_e I thought so much about what "the alleys window" would mean that I forgot to mark to review that part later.
So would look something like "In the/Through windows of the alleys?"

Comment: I don't know how to say it in natural English but yes I think it's like "In/Through the windows of the back alleys"... (hoping to see/find you in/through any of the windows facing the back alleys)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> できないことは　もう何もない

is literally like "There's nothing impossible anymore", "There's nothing I can't do now" or "Nothing is impossible now/anymore".

Breakdown:
できない can't do; impossible
こと thing
は (particle)
もう anymore
何もない nothing exists; there's nothing

> すべてかけて抱きしめてみせるよ

すべてかけて (を is omitted) → 全てを賭けて means "at all costs" "at any cost". (≂ 全てを犠牲にしても・どんな犠牲を払っても)

The ～てみせる doesn't mean "show"; it's a subsidiary verb (補助動詞) meaning "I'll definitely/surely do~~". It indicates the speaker's strong will or determination to do something. From [#9-イ on デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/211967/m0u/):

> みせる【見せる】
> 10 （補助動詞）動詞の連用形に助詞「て」の付いた形に接続して用いる。
> ㋑ 強い決意を表す。「絶対に勝ってみせる」(Indicates the speaker's strong determination. "I'll definitely win by all means.")

Comment: Thank you very much! I never imagined this possible use of "miseru"!